# Ionic - Could not determine project type (project config: .\ionic.config.json)

Tags: ionic-framework

i have a source Ionic which coded by Ionic version 1 but now Ionic version is 3, when i type "ionic serve" show this passage:

> [ERROR] Could not determine project type (project config: .\ionic.config.json).

```
    For Ionic Angular projects, make sure ionic-angular is listed as a dependency in package.json.
    For Ionic 1 projects, make sure ionic is listed as a dependency in bower.json.

    Alternatively, set type attribute in ionic.config.json to one of: ionic-angular, ionic1, custom.

    If the Ionic CLI does not know what type of project this is, ionic build, ionic serve, and other commands may
    not work. You can use the custom project type if that's okay.
```

Comment: do you have ionic.config.json? can you add it to question?

Comment: @SurajRao yes i have ionic.config.json